Job not running every hour
I try export file into folder path and run job every hour. It’s work on my local server. When I deployment on production server. I found missing hour in folder path. Please help me
My result:
2024-01-01_10:00:00.txt
2024-01-01_11:00:00.txt
2024-01-01_13:00:00.txt

My expected result:
2024-01-01_10:00:00.txt
2024-01-01_11:00:00.txt
**2024-01-01_12:00:00.txt**
2024-01-01_13:00:00.txt
..
2024-01-01_23:00:00.txt


From my experience with Quartz.net, it is not very scalable and can occasionally skip some iterations. This typically occurs due to insufficient resources (check your database and server CPU/memory usage). Additionally, remember that running it locally with a local database does not involve networking delays, unlike the production environment.
In our team, after numerous attempts to improve the stability and scalability of Quartz.net, we decided to switch to Hangfire.

Thanks! If I not switch to Hangfire and updating my ram from 64GB to 128GB , Maybe it work?
